# Events in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, events

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="admin.css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function hello(ele)
    {
        //alert(ele);
        $("#text"+ele.id).show();
        //alert(ele);
        $(ele.id).hide();
        if(typeof $(ele.id).addEventListener != 'undefined')
            {
                $(ele.id).addEventListener("keyup", printhello, false)
            }
        else if(typeof $(ele.id).attachEvent != 'undefined')
            {
                $(ele.id).attachEvent("onkeyup",printhello);
            }

        function printhello()
        {
            alert("hello");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<div class="content">
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fashion");
if(!$conn)
{
    die("connection not made ". mysqli_error($conn));
}
$query="select * from styles";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows ($result)>0)
{
    $str="<table class='styles-table'><th>id</th><th>name</th><th>image</th>";
    while($dr=  mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $str .= "<tr><td>".$dr["id"]."</td><td><input type='textbox'     id='text".$dr["id"]."' style='display:none;' value='".$dr["name"]."' /><div ondblclick='hello(this)' style='border:solid 2px black;' id='".$dr["id"]."'>".$dr["name"]."</div></td><td>".$dr["image1"]."</td></tr>" ;
    }
}
echo($str);
?>
</div>
</html>
```

In the above code no event is working,
and the jquery hide() event is working without even including jquery.
i don't know the problem , please help!

Comment: Why are you adding vanilla javascript event listeners instead of jQuery's? You're missing out on all the cross-browser normalization by not simply using the `$(selector).on('event', function(){});` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its seems you change this

`$(ele.id)` to `$('#'+ele.id)`

Example

```
$('#'+ele.id).hide();  // and every where
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess the element you bind them event are not on dom yet.
please add

```
$(document).ready(function(){//place you events bind here});
```

Comment: Yup, this would be my guess as well.

Comment: @liad is correct. To expand, here is a link to jQuery's write up on the subject. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: how can i get the ele.id to bind there, the console says ele.id not recognised

Comment: @bhawin use this $('#'+ele.id)

Comment: i can't sir , it says ele not defined

Comment: when you call hello(ele) pass the element itself like hello($("#ele")) i don't see the ele element in your code so i don't know what is it but hello(ele) will not work if you didn't have a variable name ele => var ele = "";

Comment: i saw the second answer, it solved my problem, that is where i was wrong , the event is running without placing it in $(document).ready, so sorry i can't mark your answer